# How define host flag of swagger with flask-restx?

Tags: python, flask, swagger, swagger-2.0, flask-restx

I am using the Flask-RestX to generate an automatic swagger 2.0 documentation. But I can not find how I could define the flag "host" by RestX.

I use this code to generate swagger.json automatic with RestX:

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restx import Api


def create_app() -> Flask:
    """Create Flask app."""
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # accepts both /endpoint and /endpoint/ as valid URLs
    app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/api/v1")
    return app


blueprint = Blueprint("api", __name__)
api = Api(blueprint,
          doc='/docs/',
          title="Test API",
          version="1.0",
          description="Test API")
app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":  # Only in dev
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)  # nosec
```

To get the swagger.json and save it on folder `docs/specs`, I run this script:

```
"""Export Swagger documentation automatically."""
import json
import yaml
from app import create_app

def get_swagger_json():
    """Get swagger json generated automatic by RestX."""

    with app.test_client() as client:
        swagger_doc = client.get('/api/v1/swagger.json').get_json()

    with open('docs/specs/swagger.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json.dump(swagger_doc, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)


app = create_app()
get_swagger_json()
```

I want generate a swagger.json like this:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "basePath": "/api/v1",
    "host": "myserver-prod.com.br",
    ...
}
```

But I can generate this with RestX:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "basePath": "/api/v1",
    ...
}
```

Anyone could help me in how I can do this?